# In Excel 2007, I need to convert a phone number to a serial number, preserving the last 4 digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Example: Assume the device phone number is `847-630-4459`.

- Step 1: We add a “1” to the front of the number yielding:  1-847-630-4459
- Step 2: For the first 7 digits (1-847-630), we subtract each from 10.  Eg. 10-1 = 9, 10-8 = 2, etc.
- Step 3: The new label is created as a “serial number”. The final result would look like this:

  > S/N 92634704459

I need to do this for 465 phone lines - is there a way to create a formula to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your numbers all have 10 digits then with number in A1 try this formula in B1 to convert as required

`="S/N 9"&SUMPRODUCT(MOD(-MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""),{1,2,3,4,5,6},1),10),10^{5,4,3,2,1,0})&RIGHT(A1,4)`

You can copy the formula down the column to convert your full set of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a more mathematically oriented approach:

```
="S/N 9"&(1111110-INT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")/10000))*10000+MOD(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""),10000)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t implement your instructions exactly –– it is off by one in the preceding digit when the input phone number contains a `0` (zero).  But it does satisfy your implied requirement, namely that different phone numbers should always produce different serial numbers.

And of course you can shorten that formula a little by using a helper column. 
If you set `B1` to contain `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "")`, then the serial number can be expressed as

```
="S/N 9" & (1111110-INT(B1/10000))*10000 + MOD(B1, 10000)
```

Comment: Along the same lines, `="S/N "&(10^7-LEFT(1&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""),7)+1111110)&RIGHT(A1,4)`. The key operation being 10000000-(7 digit number)+1111110.

Comment: I don’t know what your point is.  OK, you’ve improved on my answer by using `LEFT` and `RIGHT` instead of modulo arithmetic.  But A-B+C = A+C-B, so `10^7` - _expression_ + `1111110` = `10000000` + `1111110` - _expression_ = `11111110` - _expression_, and thus you have just taken that part of my answer and made it more complicated.